# In triangle ABC, prove that angle A is a right angle if and only if the length of the median from A to BC is exactly half the length of side BC.

Tags: euclidean-geometry

[image]

I drew it to scale because I was trying to notice something, but I cannot figure anything out.

Comment: Then this becomes the case of a triangle in a semi-circle.

Comment: I noticed that, but I'm afraid to make observations due to this because it isn't given that CF becomes the diameter.

Comment: "If": let $E$ be the mid-point of $CF$, then $CE = AE = EF$. Then $A,C,F$ is on a circle with centre $E$. And since $CEF$ is a straight line, it is also a diameter.

Comment: That makes complete sense. And since arc GF (longways) is 180 degrees, angle A must be a right angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"If": In $\triangle ABC$, let $E$ be the mid-point of $BC$, then $BE = AE = EC$. Then $A,B,C$ is on a circle with centre $E$.

And since $BEC$ is a straight line, it is also a diameter. $\angle A = 90^\circ$ because it is an angle in semi-circle.

---

"Only if": Duplicate $\triangle A'CB \cong\triangle ABC$, with $A'$ and $A$ on different sides of line $BC$. Then $ABA'C$ is a rectangle because $\angle A = 90^\circ$.

The median from $A$ to the mid-point of $BC$ is half of the diagonal $AA'$ of the rectangle. In a rectangle, diagonals are of equal length and bisect each other.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative. By the law of cosines,
$$ 4m_a^2 = 2b^2+2c^2-a^2,\tag{1}$$
hence $4m_a^2=a^2$ implies:
$$ b^2+c^2=a^2\tag{2}$$
from which $\widehat{BAC}=\frac{\pi}{2}$.